# Nhibernate Mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way to get references to the mapping objects that NHibernate creates from the XML files?  How about the ClassMap objects that FluentNhibernate creates?  I wanted to create some query generation functions (for row counts, etc.) using this information.  Since I went through the trouble of mapping it, I ought to have access to it in code, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Fluent ClassMaps are translated **to** XML.

The ISessionFactory exposes a `GetAllClassMetadata` method that is probably what you need.

Comment: Technically, class maps and config XML are both converted into a internal canonical set of configuration object, but I think Deigo is right on the method to access the information.

Comment: This kind of works.  The table and column data does exist, but is not directly accessible (protected members).  I can probably look deeper into this to get what I need in the end.  Thanks.